# MongoServerSelectionError: this.signal.throwIfAborted is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cors

I am getting this error while connecting to MongoDB with Node.JS.
MongoServerSelectionError: this.signal.throwIfAborted is not a function

my IP access list has 0.0.0.0/0.

## My code is here:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require("mongodb");
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.jmyw8mw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  },
});

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();
    // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log(
      "Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!"
    );
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Study Materials is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I am expecting "Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!"
But getting the aforementioned error

Comment: Hi, this error typically occurs due to compatibility issues with MongoDB Node.js driver version... So first ensure that you are using a compatible version of MongoDB Node.js driver with your MongoDB server.

Comment: my node js version is : 16.13.0
my mongodb version is : 6.4.0

can you tell me if they are compatible?

Comment: Not NodeJs itself, the driver version. What is your MongoDB Node.js driver version?

Comment: How did you fix it? it was compatibility issue?

Comment: It seems a compatibility issue for me. I had older versions of node.js and npm version. And it seems the newer Mongodb driver didn't like it. After I upgrade the node.js and npm, things started to work